# Moving wordpress / CiviCRM to another folder

Tags: wordpress

I had mysite.com set up with CiviCRM, we built a new site and then moved mysite.com to another directory and changed the subdomain to old.mysite.com. CiviCRM no longer works and I am having a hard time getting it running. From reading this: [Change URL only on WordPress+CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16114/change-url-only-on-wordpresscivicrm) I changed the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL but I am assuming I need to do more than just that as that didn't work. If anyone could give me some more information that would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Can you edit your question to include the version of CiviCRM you are using? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's also all these in civicrm.settings.php

`// Additional settings generated by installer:
$civicrm_paths['wp.frontend.base']['url'] = 'http://domain.org/wpcivi/';
$civicrm_paths['wp.backend.base']['url'] = 'http://domain.org/wpcivi/wp-admin/';
$civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = 'http://domain.org/wpcivi/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm';`

and further down there's `global $civicrm_root;`

and site urls

and double check in admin:

- resource url
- directories
- CMS database integration
- CMS database